# How to disable "drag" on Table data

Tags: javascript, html

https://codepen.io/JoshTheGray/pen/dmmBYe

I'm attempting to disable the ability to "click and drag" colors onto the grid, because when you do so, it fills in the entire grid with the selected color.

So far I've attempted to make add `draggable=false` to

`<table>` & every `<tr>`/`<td>`, which has no effect.

---

I also tried adding this to my body tag, which seems to also have no effect.

`<BODY ondragstart="return false;" ondrop="return false;">`

---

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Draggable** is not the problem, the problem is that the target of the click event will vary if you move the mouse between the **mousedown** and the **mouseup**. It's a weird behavior that makes sense in a way. What you could do is replace the **click** event with **mousedown** or **mouseup**, depending on the expected behavior.

```
mainGrid.addEventListener('mouseup', function(event) {
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/KoGMbE

Comment: I didn't even factor in that the event.target was changing... good point. Thank you!